# how get final price with jquery and checkbox

Tags: jquery, forms, checkboxlist

I'm new here.
Can anyone help me for how create a form like this site?
https://www.socialengine.com/buy-social-engine
I mean that checkbox group 
and that Total: $299 on the right side
I search a lot about this
but fail all time.
If anyone can give me an example code 
I will be happy. 
Thank you.
And can I use something like this?

```
$(function() {
    var 
    jqDdl = $("#mainselectqs"),
    onChange = function(event) {
```

Comment: what have you done so far? You cant expect people to program for you.

Comment: sorry if i dont put any codes.. im really know less about checkboxs work ... and how i must get value from (checkbox gorup) when its checked ..thats why i dont put any codes sorry again

Comment: $('#lifesteps-group-0 :checked').each(function() {
  if (allSteps.length === 0) {
      allSteps = $(this).val();
}
else {
    allSteps = allSteps + ',' + $(this).val();
     }
}); these are some code i test it but fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/97qWc/)**

```
<input type='checkbox' value='10' />10
<input type='checkbox' value='20' />20
<input type='checkbox' value='30' />30
<input type='checkbox' value='40' />40
<input type='checkbox' value='50' />50
<div id='total'></div>

var init_price = 200;
$('#total').html(init_price);
var tot = 0;
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked')){
      tot = Number($('#total').html()) + Number($(this).val());
   } else {
       tot = Number($('#total').html()) - Number($(this).val());
   }

   $('#total').html(tot);
});​
```